# Are tungsten ammunition cores still to be found on European WW2 battlefields?

Tags: world-war-two, tanks, metallurgy

With ammunition sometimes missing target and penetrator cores sometimes exiting the other side of the target, i imagine tungsten cores fired during WW2 were seldom collected. Are they still found today?

Comment: `I imagine tungsten cores fired during WW2 were seldom collected` Why do you? While it is possible that some are still hidden a) as opposite to WWI & II shells and aviation bombs, they were fired in a flat trajectory (less chance of them becoming buried) and b) tungsten is a valuable metal. I would guess also that less of those were fired than shells or bombs, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: I simply suppose they were not found.The flat trajectorys made them go somewhere uncalculated. In a tank battle, they probaly dit not think about the area behind the target a lot, nor had both sides the opportunity to search the area. And i don't think the winning side felt like doing so either. The trajectory lowered after some time of flight and shells hit the ground with some residual energy. This happend with more energy if the landscape had hills. Maybe they exploded and propelled the penetrator core into the ground.